# Copy sequential files into sequential directories

Tags: linux, terminal, python, perl, cp

I need to copy multiple, sequential files into sequential directories. The files have the julian date (day of year) with other info in the file name.  The directories are listed by julian date (day of year).  I need each file to correspond with the julian date.

To clarify....

I have 365 files labeled "test_001.txt" through "test_365.txt" in "/home/aaa". Each file needs to be moved into it's own directory in "/data" labeled "001" through "365".

Hope this clears it up. Thanks!

Comment: Example data please

Comment: Are the source files and directories in the same place or in different parts of the filesystem?

Comment: They are in different parts, but on the same server.

Comment: @gbh Please edit your most and make it more clearer with some clear example.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
for K in $(seq -w 1 365)
do
    mv *_${K}.* "/data/$K" 2>/dev/null
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist!  But that only moved one file, the one labeled with 365.  I need to move all the files.  Thanks again!  That is a great start!

Comment: @gbh sorry, I'm currently on a phone and the `seq` lost its starting 1 value. Post edited

Comment: Thanks again!  But sadly, it had the same result.  I did figure it out, with the help of your code.  It is below.

Comment: @gbh perhaps your version of seq doesn't have the `-w` option, which ensures all output sequences have the same length (i.e. three characters in this scenario)? Other than that I can't see why this shouldn't work for you - unless your files don't match the glob `*_NNN.*` for numeric values of `NNN`. I suppose you could use `test_${K}.txt` if you want to be precise about the matching.

Answer (score -1):

`for K in $(seq -f "test_%200g" 365); do cp *_${K}.* "/data/$K" 2>/dev/null; done`

From what I've found out, it appears that in the "seq" command, the '%2' represents an integer and each '0' represents a place, i.e. ones, tens.  The 'g' closes the expression.  I may be wrong, but it works!  Thanks for the help!